# How "monkey --port port" work?

Tags: android, testing, monkey

I see that there is a option of monkey command in android adb shell. 
That is, "monkey --port port". i know it is a monkey client to receive server data, 
but how it work indeed? 
Is it related with com.android.command.monkey?

```
adb shell monkey --port port
```